# Jquery on uncheck of of any checkbox get id

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery, and I need to show the id of a checkbox when it is unchecked. How can I accomplish this?

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){ 
    alert(this.id); 

    if($(this).is(':unchecked')) {
         alert(this.id); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: " I could not find a suitable example"   - i don't know about that

Comment: Please check what I have

Comment: @WebDev, you're fairly close to a solution but there is not a `:unchecked` that I'm aware of. Please see my solution below for more details. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4q3c4/)** for a working example.

Given your code:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){ 
    alert(this.id);     
    if($(this).is(':unchecked')) {
         alert(this.id); 
    } 
});
```

You would need to change `:unchecked` to `:not(:checked)`. jQuery has never had an `:unchecked` filter. Other than that you were fairly close.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function(){
   if($(this).is(":not(:checked)"))
      alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update after change in OP**

You can check the unchecked checkbox using length on its click as given below.

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/inixik/1/edit)**

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){ 
    alert(this.id); 

    if($(this).not(':checked').length) {
         alert(this.id); 
    } 
});
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsbin.com/inixik/1/edit)

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    if(this.checked)
      alert(this.id + " checked");
    else
      alert(this.id + " un-checked");

});
```

or

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){

     alert($(this).attr('id'));

});
```

or with checkboxes have class = "chkclass"

```
 $('.chkclass').click(function(){

     alert(this.id);

});
```

Comment: This will check if it is clicked. How do I check if it is unchecked from a checked state.

Comment: if(this.checked){} or if($(this).is(':checked'){}

Comment: I have modified your code to make it work and updated my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these line should work for you.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    $checkbox = $(this);

    if(!$checkbox.is(':checked'))
        alert($checkbox .attr("id"));
});
```

Or if there is a possibility that the checkboxes are added dynamically use jquery [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on("click", function() {
    $checkbox = $(this);

    if(!$checkbox.is(':checked'))
        alert($checkbox .attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: I would offer a .on  option to .live  , but so far yours is the only one that checks that checkbox is now unchecked like OP asked

Answer (score 0):

Do something like below:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").live("click", function() {
    if (!$(this).attr("checked")) {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    }
});
```

Comment: `live()` is deprecated, use `on()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no selector called **':unchecked'**

You are almost close,,    Try **:checked**  instead

```
$(function() {

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {

         if(! $(this).is(':checked')){
            alert( 'ID of the current checkbox is : ' + this.id );
         }
    })

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/2v45X/)